# Can reports be generated for Resources?

Tags: report-chart

I have a requirement where I have a number of `Resources` and I'll be allocating the resources to the events. Now I need a report where I need to show all the resources and the dates in which they're booked. I am not able to find the `Resource` object so is there anyway to do it?

The Resource I'm talking about is the `Public Calendars and Resources`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resource is a type of invitee. A standard report exists to show events and invitees: Under Activity Reports select the Events with Invitees.

Now if you customize this report, you can add a field filter, and filter on the invitee type to show 'resources'.

You have to have created resource calendars of course to see them.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using the standard report that exists under Activity Report as follows

> Activity Report -> Events with Invitees
>   Under the Report section of SalesForce.
>       This can be customized based on the invitee type to show the resources and  respective 
>       Resources must be added to view them.